# Pluralize Django message

Tags: django

I have the following code to display a message when a custom action is executed in the Admin site:

```
messages.info(request, '%s posts marked as Draft' % queryset.count())
```

What is the best way to pluralize that message for when the count is greater than 1?

```
1 post marked as Draft
```

```
3 posts marked as Draft
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pluralize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize) (and probably don't use the older style `%` formatting):

```python
from django.template.defaultfilters import pluralize

post_count = queryset.count()
messages.info(
    request, '{} {} marked as Draft'.format(
        post_count, pluralize(post_count, 'post,posts')))
```

Comment: You are trying to use single quotes (`'post'`) inside a single quoted f-string. Change one of them to double quotes.

Comment: I shouldn't be allowed to code but I think that's normal after a 48-hours shift. Thank you.